# Swig-wrapped Rust code called by Android Java expects uncoded symbol "log"

Tags: java, android, rust, swig, dynamic-library

I'm trying to write an Android app which calls some Rust code via swig. I have written a simple test for the linkages. A version that has an ordinary Java main program works fine. My Android version fails with an error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol
>   "log" referenced by
>   "/data/app/hk.jennyemily.work.try3-1/lib/x86_64/libsimpleswig.so"...
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:989)

My Rust code does not import "log".

So what do I do to fix this?

The Android Java basically only does the following so far (I have not yet coded the calls to the library):

```java
static {
    System.loadLibrary("simpleswig");
}
```

Here is my Rust code:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

pub struct SimpleData {
    pub str: CString,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn newSimpleData() -> *mut SimpleData {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(SimpleData {
        str: CString::new("hello").unwrap(),
    }))
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn say(ptr: *mut SimpleData) -> *const c_char {
    let sd = unsafe {
        assert!(!ptr.is_null());
        &mut *ptr
    };
    sd.str.as_ptr()
}
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn release(ptr: *mut SimpleData) {
    if ptr.is_null() {
        return;
    }
    unsafe {
        let _ = Box::from_raw(ptr);
    }
}
```

There is also the basic Swig code for wrapping the Rust code.

The Swig and Rust code is linked into a dynamic library (.so).

*Edit: the actual C compile and link line is:*
  `$CC -shared $SIMPDIR/simple_wrap.c $SIMPDIR/libsimple.a -o $SIMPDIR/libsimpleswig.so -I"${JAVALOC}/include" -I"${JAVALOC}/include/linux"`

Here is the stand-alone Java main program, which works without any problems with the same Rust and Swig code.

```java
public class test {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("simpleswig");
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.out.println("starting...");
        simpleswig.SWIGTYPE_p_SimpleData sd = simpleswig.simpleswig.newSimpleData();
        System.out.println( simpleswig.simpleswig.say(sd));
        System.out.println("releasing...");
        simpleswig.simpleswig.release(sd);
        System.out.println("done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Guessing here, but is log part of the rust runtime?

Comment: Not related, but you can use [`NonNull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html), for example, in `release`: `let _ = NonNull::new(ptr).map(|p| unsafe { Box::from_raw(p.as_ptr()) });`

Comment: @flexo there's a log crate in std (https://docs.rs/log/0.4.6/log/), but I don't call it explicitly. Do I need to link in a Rust runtime library?

Comment: Can you add `-lm` when linking your `simpleswig` library?

Comment: @MartinEllison that's my hunch, because otherwise I can't see where you'll be getting one from when java loads your library.

Comment: @Jmb That fixed it thanks (once I put the `-lm` *before* the `-o ...`). Sorry for the delay in replying but I have been away.